# Como Listar mais de uma linha do banco em uma Listview usando JDBC?

Tags: android, listview, jdbc

Como listar mais de 1 dado do banco usando JDBC em uma ListView em Android? Tenho em um usuário 13 linhas, e gostaria de recuperar as 13 e não apenas 1. Abaixo o código que utilizo:

```
import android.os.Bundle;                      

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public  class Tela2 extends MyActivity {

    static TextView useron;

    static ListView listgeral;

    static EditText email, descricao, codigo;


    Button atualiza;


    TabHost.TabSpec spec1, spec2;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela2);


        //Crio um objeto tabhost
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();
        //pego a váriavel do tabhost para setar as configurações
        spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Aba 1");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec1.setIndicator("Meus Pacotes");


        spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Aba 2");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec2.setIndicator("Novo rastreamento");


        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);


        //Crio uma váriavel contendo os componentes "TextView"
        listgeral = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.valor1);


        atualiza = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.atualiza));


        //Crio um TextView de usuario online
        useron = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usuario);


        //Seto o valor que é recebido da classe "MyActivity"
        useron.setText(dominios);



        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";

        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        //String contendo o usu�rio do banco
        String userbanco = "kappauni";

        //String contendo a senha do usuario do banco
        String passbanco = "teste";

        java.sql.Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userbanco, passbanco);
            Statement st = null;
            st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = null;

            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM encomendas where dominio ='"+useron.getText()+"'");

while (rs.next()){


            String valorcodigo = rs.getString("codigorastreio");
                String  valordescricao = rs.getString("descricao");


                String[] stringcodigo = {valorcodigo.toString()+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+valordescricao.toString()};


                ArrayAdapter<String> arraycodigo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringcodigo);

                listgeral.setAdapter(arraycodigo);

}

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    //Método que ao clicar no botão adicionar, ele vai adicionar os valores no banco


    public void Adicionar(View add) throws Exception {


        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.form1);


        descricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.form2);

        codigo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.form3);


        BancoInsert conexaoinsert = new BancoInsert();

        conexaoinsert.insert();

    }


//BOtão de atualizar

    public void atualizar(View upd){


        Toast.makeText(Tela2.this,"Atualizou",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


        }
```

Comment: Você dá esse monte de espaço em seu código mesmo ou ficou mal formatado quando postou aqui? Fica difícil acompanhar o código.

Comment: Usando banco MySQL localhost em um dispositivo Android? O próprio Android tem o SQLite, porque não usa ele?

Comment: É apenas para teste, por que o mesmo vai ser usado em minha hospedagem como já utilizava.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, acredito que você seja novo no mundo Android. Não é possível e nem recomendado acessar um banco externo diretamente a partir de um aplicativo Android. A forma recomendada de acessar dados externos da sua aplicação é através de requisições REST de seu web server, o seu app vai consumir esses dados, podendo fazer outras requisições para atualizar o banco, mas sempre através de um web server. Veja esse post (em inglês) sobre isso:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233178/2129877

Uma lib muito boa e simples para fazer chamadas REST é o retrofit

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Sobre o seu código, o setAdapter() só precisa ser feito uma única vez, por isso não precisa estar dentro do "for". O Correto seria você passar um array de strings onde cada string é a tupla (linha) do banco.

[]s

Comment: Possível até que é... Mas, como você falou, não é recomendado. :)